# why making processors is Monopolized on 3 companies

Tags: processor

why only there are only 3 companies allowed to make processor "intel - AMD -apple" why others  can't make one ..

i know that making processor is difficult and needs a huge techno , but what about google or samsung  aren't they have the qualified techno ? so why they use others' processors

Comment: Why not use them?

Comment: What about ARM, Freescale/Motorola, NXP, Texas Instruments, Qualcomm...? Hell, most companies use ARM cores in their processors.

Comment: You're mistaken; Apple uses Intel processors. Intel and AMD are the biggest companies for PCs, but there are plenty of other CPUs for embedded systems like TI, Atmel and Microchip.

Comment: Hello, haven't you heard of Texas Instruments, Samsung, Qualcomm, or NVIDIA? They ship billions of ARM processors a year. Or do you mean why so few companies design their own processors?

Comment: Flagging for low quality.  OP has obviously not done any research.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about manufacturing and economics.

Comment: A little  wikipedia search shows an extensive list of companies in the microcontroller http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_microcontrollers i suspect not all of them have their own foundries but they do design them

Comment: Many others do. Anyone who wants can. |Google do not make the roads their autonomous cars drive on, they largely do not make the cars. They do not make the hard drives in their immense mission critical data stores. They do not make the computers that the CPU's operate in., They do not make their LCDs - or their desks, curtains, buildings ... .  
Processors are specialist devices made well by people who want that as their core business. That's not Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there are plenty of other Processor manufacturers, ARM noted above are probably bigger than the ones you named by processors shipped, but others, such as VIA who also make processors for the same X86 and X86-64 instruction sets used in Intel and AMD 32 and 64-bit processors.

Processor companies require architecture volume to persuade third parties to support a platform.

Imagine if a new chip manufacturer with their own architecture and instruction set, came to market: 1st they'd either need to make their own System-on-Chip or motherboard, 2nd they'd need to code all of the basic software, peripherals and in the first instance either code or port an operating system to their brand new hardware to convince others of its potential.

In short, unless someone could demonstrate exceptional power usage, or alternatively a significant increase in the performance/cost ratio, they would struggle to convince partners in hardware, software and peripherals to support their new platform.

Comment: But, if you're hell-bent on using your own instruction set, no one is stopping you from synthesizing your own soft core processor on an FPGA.

Comment: ARM does not make any processors, they juts *license* their design to companies that produce products that contain ARM IP (NXP, Atmel, TI, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Any company that feels that they can be competitive in the market (or even those that feel the need to lose money by the bushel) is free to make a processor.